# Can not access SQL Server Express using Public IP TalkTalk Super Router

Tags: sql-server, connection, sql-server-express

I'm having a trouble to access SQL Server Express via internet. I did create a database, login and password, I have access to it if I put on my connection my local IP, but from outside when I'm using public IP I can not log in.

I have:

1. Enabled TCP/IP
2. On the server I have added TCP protocols: 1433
3. I've disabled McAfee firewall and added to windows firewall SQL server and SQL Browser.
4. Added to my TalkTalk super router port forward to my laptop.
5. In Router firewall selected DMZ as my Laptop to allow all.

I have recorded what did I try
https://youtu.be/wAgXMUsItcM

What am I missing? Or what's not configured properly. I have also try to add in the router port forward for SQL Server Browser as 1434, and added to the firewall

Comment: SQL Server **Express** doesn't allow **remote connections** by default - have you enabled that feature?

Comment: Hi, on Server Properties there's tick on **allow remote connection on this server**.